# Updating string.empty values from a Databinded Textbox into an MS Access Database using VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

First time asking here on stackoverflow.com

Now here's the situation:

I have a databinded textbox called middleNameTb.

Here's my binding code for it:

```
middleNameTb.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", _bizProfile.DataSet.Tables(0), "MiddleName", True, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged))
```

Now let's say we got a name, "Luke Anakin Skywalker". So the middle name is Anakin and it's showing on the middleNameTb. Now we try to erase it from the middleNameTb using (backspace) and leave the middleNameTb blank/empty. Then hit my save button that does the updating.

Here's my update code:

```
Me.UpdateCommand.CommandText = "UPDATE Profile SET [MiddleName] = @MiddleName"

Me.UpdateCommand.Connection = Me.Connection

Me.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@MiddleName", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 50, "MiddleName")

Me.DataAdapter.Update(Me.DataSet)
```

My MS Access MiddleName column's allow zero length is set to false which is what I wanted. Because I don't want it putting 0 length string values if the value is just blank.

After hitting the save button, here's the exception I get:
Field 'BasicInfo.MiddleName' cannot be a zero-length string.

Now the question is: How can we set a condition, maybe like an if statement on checking if the value is EmptyOrNull, it will insert a Dbnull.Value instead?

Now I know a code like this,

```
Me.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@MiddleName", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 50, "MiddleName").Value = If(Me.MiddleName = String.Empty, DBNull.Value, Me.MiddleName)
```

But you see I am updating values from databinded controls so I don't hardcode the control or variable to set the value of the parameter.

I hope I have explained everything. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle this in your SQL statement by checking for a zero length string:

```
Me.UpdateCommand.CommandText = "UPDATE Profile SET [MiddleName] = CASE WHEN (@MiddleName IS NULL OR LEN(@MiddleName) > 1) THEN @MiddleName ELSE NULL END"
```

Alternatively, you may also be able to leverage the [ConvertEmptyStringToNull](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.parameter.convertemptystringtonull(v=vs.110).aspx) Property to avoid the extra SQL.